# Filling all the available space horizontally and vertically, with divs

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to achieve the following layout without tables or JavaScript.

[image: The layout]

It's basically the common layout of desktop software. Some toolbars and the actual content in the middle. I'm trying to replicate the layout in a web-application.

I need all the toolbars to be flexible and optional. So in one state there might only be the top toolbar with 3 rows of icons and in another case all four toolbars with just a little content.

The application will be using 100% of the document width / height and must not overflow. However, the div in the middle has overflow: auto and should scale in every direction. There might be a case where all the toolbars are hidden and then the middle div should take the whole document.

The application requires JavaScript and doesn't support IE6 at all, but I'm still looking for a cross-browser way to do this with CSS.

It's very easy and clean to do it with a table and I know how to do it with JavaScript, but I have come across this problem multiple times and would like to stop using tables.

Comment: I don't have current code. I usually tackle this problem with a table, since I don't know any working way to do it with divs. I could create a fixed example of the layout, but I think the image in my question tells enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done cross browser compatible.
Use jQuery javascript plugin: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Any way to do it with modern browsers and CSS3?

Comment: Maybe in HTML 5:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/04/designing-a-html-5-layout-from-scratch/

http://www.net-kit.com/html5-css3-layout-tutorials-and-templates/

Comment: @jmav, I'm curious why this *can't be done cross browser compatible*. I think that is a stretch. I don't see anything in the OP that would leave me to believe that, especially when IE6 does not need to be supported.

Comment: I'm also curious. Creating this with a table is extremely easy, clean and works in all the browsers. Why it can't be done with divs?

Comment: @Jason McCreary, I sad it couldn't be done without JavaScript.
@Ezdaroth some browser's doesn't support % div height, an there are some issues with div widths. Both: read question again.

Comment: @jmav, I still disagree. I have written dozens of sites under this format with HTML and CSS. Now, I agree about using tables, the OP listed they did not want to do it with tables. But they also said they didn't want to do it with JavaScript. So along those lines, maybe *you* should have read the question again.

Comment: I did and the answer is: It can't be done cross browser compatible. then i sad to Use jQuery javascript plug-in. One more thing: did you see attached image? There is everywhere dynamic height, dynamic width.
If you can do it with div's and CSS and IE 6 compatible :) then you are the king who beats every CSS master/guru.